# SSRS 2012 configuration error when trying to use a custom authentication extension

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am attempting to implement a custom security extension for an instance of SQL Reporting Server 2012, and am having some trouble. This extension is to hook into an existing application that uses Forms authentication.

I've implemented the appropriate required interfaces (`IAuthenticationExtension` and `IAuthorizationExtension`) and, as far as I know, have changed the configuration files appropriately (as per MSDN's instructions). Also, I've copied the assemblies over to the report server (to both the ReportServer and ReportManager's bin directories).

The error I'm getting is:
`library!ReportServer_0-4!44c!11/20/2015-15:41:12:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: Could not load Authentication extension, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;`

I've verified that reverting back to the report server's default settings (and thus changing the authentication mode back to `Windows`) works, so there is nothing wrong with the installation of the software. I've also read this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/162616/configuration-error-could-not-load-authentication-extension)  over at ServerFault, but I don't really want to have to rebuild SSRS if I don't have to.

At this point, I'm not trying to do anything fancy--I'm just trying to make sure my extension is loading properly.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I in fact found the problem. Make sure when you're setting up your custom extension in `rsreportserver.config` that you specify `Forms` for the `Name` attribute for the `Extension` element (if you are doing Forms authentication). This is under the `Extensions` parent element

For example,

`<Authentication>
    <Extension Name="Forms" Type="<TypeName>,<AssemblyName>"/>
</Authentication>`

I'm guessing since SSRS loads specific HTTP modules to handle various forms of authentication (e.g. Windows, Forms, Passport, etc.), it is looking for the name of one of those modules when adding a custom extension.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281383.aspx):

> In practice, deploying a custom authentication extension requires multiple steps that include copying assemblies and application files, modifying configuration files, and testing.

It sounds like you have modified the report server configuration, but the error seems to indicate that the custom authentication assembly is not available on the report server - has this been installed on the server?

Comment: I've edited my question. Yes, I made sure that the assemblies are in the bin directories of both the ReportServer and ReportManager folders. Is there something else there that I've missed?

Comment: The MSDN articles seem to be pretty light on detail regarding how to actually deploy a custom security extension, there is a lot more information on the product samples page for the sample security extension - it looks like there might be some additional configuration required: http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2012%21Security%20Extension%20Sample&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Looks like I had an error in my configuration files--I am at least not getting the error above now. I suppose the moral of the story is to check and re-check for mispellings or missing elements. I went through the sample and then modified it to use my extension.

Comment: This `ServerConfigurationErrorException` got me: `Could not create Extension of type: Authenticationname: None, ...`.
The cause in my case was the inconsistency in the standard example between `Authorization` and `AuthenticationExtension`. I forgot the "Extension" in the typename in `rsreportserver.config`:<br/>
`Type="Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity.AuthenticationExtension, ...`.
Maybe they could at least mention a more specific error (e.g. the failing type-name) in the error-message.